# Taylor of a function within an integral

Tags: definite-integrals, taylor-expansion

Let $a$ and $b$ two real such that $a<b$. Let $F$ be the function defined by
$$
F\left(x\right)=\int_{a}^{b}f\left(x,t\right)\text{d}t
$$
Suppose that
$$
f\left(x,t\right)\underset{(0)}{=}a\left(t\right)+b\left(t\right)x+c\left(t\right)x^2+o\left(x^2\right)
$$
where $o\left(x^2\right)$ depends on $t$. For example
$$
F\left(x\right)=\int_{1}^{8}\frac{\cos\left(tx\right)}{t}\text{d}t
$$

How can I clearly justify (and is it always true ?) that
$$
F\left(x\right)\underset{(0)}{=}\int_{a}^{b}a\left(t\right)\text{d}t+\left(\int_{a}^{b}b\left(t\right)\text{d}t\right)x+\left(\int_{a}^{b}c\left(t\right)\text{d}t\right)x^2+o\left(x^2\right)
$$
What's bothering me is that in the taylor expansion of $f$ there is a $t$ hidden in the $o\left(x^2\right)$ and I was wondering if we could be sure it could be neglected.

Comment: Should that be $o(x^3)$?

Comment: The equality $
f\left(x,t\right)\underset{(0)}{=}a\left(t\right)+b\left(t\right)x+c\left(t\right)x^2+o\left(x^2\right)
$ is ambiguous. Is your $o(x^2)$ independent from $t$?

Comment: No it isn't independant from $t$.

Answer (score 1):

If the $o(x^2)$ in

$$
f\left(x,t\right)\underset{(0)}{=}a\left(t\right)+b\left(t\right)x+c\left(t\right)x^2+o\left(x^2\right)
$$ is independent from $t$, for all $\epsilon \gt 0$ it exists $\delta \gt 0$ with

$$
\vert f\left(x,t\right) - (a\left(t\right)+b\left(t\right)x+c\left(t\right)x^2 ) \vert \le \epsilon x^2
$$ for all $\vert x \vert \le \delta$ and all $t \in [a,b]$. From there it follows that for $\epsilon \gt 0$

$$
\left\vert F\left(x\right)-\left(\int_{a}^{b}a\left(t\right)\text{d}t+\left(\int_{a}^{b}b\left(t\right)\text{d}t\right)x+\left(\int_{a}^{b}c\left(t\right)\text{d}t\right)x^2\right)\right\vert
\le (b-a)\epsilon x^2$$ and the desired result.